# Jackson 2.11.4 doesn't support deserialize LocalDate which pattern is [yyyy-MM-dd] when set [lenient = OptBoolean.FALSE] in [@JsonFormat]?

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, localdate

### **WHAT:**

When I set the `@JsonFormat` -> `lenient = OptBoolean.FALSE` for a field which type is LocalDate, it says `Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor`. The `jackson` version is `2.11.4`, SpringBoot version is `2.4.2`.

---

### Details:

I upgraded SpringBoot to `2.4.2` this morning, but my tests failed when deserializing a field which type is LocalDate.

Here is my code:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.OptBoolean;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Demo {

    public Demo(){}

    public Demo(LocalDate localDate){
        this.localDate = localDate;
    }

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy/MM/dd", lenient = OptBoolean.FALSE)
    private LocalDate localDate;

    public LocalDate getLocalDate() {
        return localDate;
    }

    public void setLocalDate(LocalDate localDate) {
        this.localDate = localDate;
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity<String> test(@RequestBody Demo demo) {
        var localDate = demo.getLocalDate().toString();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(localDate);
    }
}
```

**when**

```sh
curl -L -X GET 'http://localhost:8080/test' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "localDate": "2020/01/15"
}'
```

**It shows**

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String "2020/01/15": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDate: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2020/01/15' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {YearOfEra=2020, MonthOfYear=1, DayOfMonth=15},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String "2020/01/15": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDate: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2020/01/15' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {YearOfEra=2020, MonthOfYear=1, DayOfMonth=15},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 18] (through reference chain: com.example.demo.Demo["localDate"])]
```

But when I set the `lenient` to `TRUE` or remove the annotation, it works well.

Does anyone know the actual reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer.

When we set `lenient = OptBoolean.FALSE`, it will use strict mode for `DateTimeFormatter`. See issue [jackson-modules-java8 #199](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/issues/148) and [jackson-modules-java8 #199](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/issues/148).

The error says `Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {YearOfEra=2020, MonthOfYear=1, DayOfMonth=15}`.

In [java8 `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns), here are 3 lines comments:

```
Symbol  Meaning                     Presentation      Examples
------  -------                     ------------      -------
 G       era                         text              AD; Anno Domini; A
 u       year                        year              2004; 04
 y       year-of-era                 year              2004; 04
```

It says the `y` means year-of-era, and the `u` actual means year.

So update the pattern `yyyy-MM-dd` to `uuuu-MM-dd`, it works.

And if you want to use `y` in the pattern, it's better to use `G` together to specific the era.

See issue: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/issues/199